# How do I find the critical points of ln(y+2)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions

Im trying to find the critical points of this first order differential equation.

$$\large{{dy\over dx}=y\ln(y+2)}$$

I already got one critical point of $y=0$.

If I set $\ln(y+2) = 0$ Im unsure how to isolate y. Would I multiply each side by $e$?

Comment: $\ln 1=0$ and $y+2=1$ i.e $y=-1$,if this is what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want the critical points of $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$, $y(x)$ or $\ln(y+2)$?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern, "critical point of a differential equation" typically means points where the derivative is zero.  I think I've only seen this in the context of systems of first-order ODEs.  But I guess one equation is technically a system.  Eh...

Comment: The derivative of the unknown function or the derivative of the equation itself?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern I wanted to know how to find the critical points of ln(y+2)

Comment: yeah! thats exactly what I was asking. thanks @kingW3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the critical points of the equation, set $dy/dx = 0$.  So then $y \ln(y+2) = 0$.

You've already found $y = 0$.

The other one is from $\ln(y+2) = 0$.  This is a logarithmic equation and is equivalent to the exponential equation $y+2 = e^0$.  Since $e^0 = 1$, then we have $y = -1$.

Comment: Thanks , this is a great help!